# Get the name of a class as a string

Tags: c++, class, c-preprocessor

I have a macro:

```
#define DECLARE_STATE_CLASS(T)                                            \
static void create(TGE::StateListener* Parent, const std::string name)    \
{                                                                         \
    T* myState = new T();                                                 \
    myState->parent = Parent;                                             \
    Parent->manageState(name, myState);                                   \
}
```

which I place in all classes derived from the base class State. I use the state name as a string because all states are stored in a vector, and so I have to have a function that polls through the vector and returns the state with the name you requested. I would like to remove the necessity for the user to give each state it's own name. Instead, I want the name to be the name of the class. How can I do something like

```
#define DECLARE_STATE_CLASS(T)                                            \
static void create(TGE::StateListener* Parent)                            \
{                                                                         \
    T* myState = new T();                                                 \
    myState->parent = Parent;                                             \
    Parent->manageState(T.toString(), myState);                           \
}
```

instead of what I'm currently doing? I imagine the best way would be to get myState's typename and somehow convert that to a string. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
Parent->manageState(#T, myState);
```

in your macro. See [gcc online docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html#Stringification).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `#` to create a string from the argument of the macro:

```
#define DECLARE_STATE_CLASS(T)                                            \
static void create(TGE::StateListener* Parent)                            \
{                                                                         \
    T* myState = new T();                                                 \
    myState->parent = Parent;                                             \
    Parent->manageState( #T , myState);                                   \
}
```